# Github Account Recovery

Tags: authentication, github

I have a problem signing into Github with my account. I used Microsoft Authenticator App for authorization but after a month I reset my phone and all accounts in my authenticator have been deleted. Now if I want to sign in to GitHub wants to verify the code from Authenticator but I don't have it anymore. If I want to add a GitHub account to Authenticator he wants to sign in to GitHub but that was impossible.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/recovering-your-account-if-you-lose-your-2fa-credentials

Comment: Thanks I forgot about recovery codes